# couldn't parse YAML at line 21 column 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

i'm trying to get the pg gem to work in an app.  I've successfully installed postgresql on my system, MAC OSx Lion, i'm assuming that /config/database.yml is the file in question because I've been hacking on it to get the db connection set, which wasn't working before but now is so I assume there is some problem with the database.yml file.  on a side note i know that the posgresql is working because i can createdb's but i cannot enter the rails db console, same error as below

```
  development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dbc2_development
  pool: 5
  username: dbc2
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

  test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dbc2_test
  pool: 5
  username: dbc2
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

when I try to run rake db:create:all I'm getting the blow error issues

```
rake aborted! (<unknown>): couldn't parse YAML at line 21 column 0
```

what other details can I add to make this relevant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the appropriate tabbing in front of  your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you. I followed this comment https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spree-user/HitmdVxaYgI/Zepkg3wvSwkJ and that fixed my issue

> Setted another YAML parser at the top of my `boot.rb` file:
>
> ```
> require 'yaml' 
> YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this fix but 'syck' produced erroneous results for a complex YAML file.  I found installing latest libyaml fixed the original problem without any errors.  See http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML